# Why does $(g\circ f)'(x_0)=g'(f(x_0))\circ f'(x_0)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, definition

I had a Multivariable calculus class this morning and the teacher showed us a proposition that I'm not quite sure I understand. The proposition is the following:

> Let:
>
> - $D\subset \mathbb R^n $
> - $D^* \subset  \mathbb R^m$
> - $x_0 \in D$
> - $f:D \to D^*$ be a differential function at $x_0$
> - $g: D^* \to \mathbb R^p$ be a differential function at $f(x_0)$
>
> Then $g\circ f$ is differential at $x_0$ and: $$(g\circ f)'(x_0)=g'(f(x_0))\circ f'(x_0)$$

My problem with this proposition is that I'm not understanding two things:

1. I understand derivatives of functions $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ (Things like partial derivatives, directional derivatives, etc...) and I understand that the derivative of such function is a scalar, But what is the definition of the derivative of a function $f: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$? I don't recall my teacher showing us the meaning of such derivative.
2. My second question is, in the Rhs of the equality, why do we have $g'(f(x_0))\circ f'(x_0) $ instead of $g'(f (x_0)). f'(x_0) $? I don't' understand why we are using composition of functions. Does that mean that $(g\circ f)'(x_0) $ is a function?

Comment: 1. The link that you showed me only applies to functions $r: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^m$, in this context we are dealing with functions $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$
2. It's not a typo, I asked that to the teacher and the said that it's supposed to be $\circ$ instead of $.$ @VIVID

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Point 1**

Regarding the definition of the derivative of a map $f : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$, you should look at what the Fréchet derivative is. See [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative). The Fréchet derivative at each point $a \in \mathbb R^n$ is a linear map $f^\prime(a) : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$. See also what [the Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) is.

In general, the derivative of a map $f : U \to V$ defined between two linear spaces $U,V$ is a map $f^\prime : U \to \mathcal L(U,V)$ where $\mathcal L(U,V)$ denotes the linear space of the linear maps between $U$ and $V$. **The derivative $f^\prime$ of $f$ maps each point of the domain of $f$ to a linear map!**

**Point 2**

When you understand that the derivative is a linear map, then using composition (of linear maps) for the derivative of the composition of maps makes perfect sense.

**Comments**

Your sentence *...I understand that the derivative of such function is a scalar...* is not correct. The derivative of a map $g : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ at a point $ a \in \mathbb R^n$ is **not a scalar**. It is a linear form from $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R$. And the derivative $g^\prime$ itself is a map $ g^\prime : \mathbb R^n \to \left(\mathbb R^n\right)^\prime$ where $\left(\mathbb R^n\right)^\prime$ stands for the [dual space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_space) of $\mathbb R^n$.

**By understanding all this, you'll make a big jump in your comprehension of what the derivative really is!**